# how to round a vector consists of numbers,NA, and NaN

Tags: r

What is the best way to round a vector that consists of numbers, NA, and NaN.  I don't want to omit the NA or NaN because I want to retain the order of the numbers.

```
x = c(2,3,4,NA,"NaN",3, 5)
round(x,2)  #does not work
```

Edits: Error in round(x, 2) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: what is multimodal reflection sorting?

Comment: Do you have a string `"NaN"` or `NaN` number in x?

Comment: I don't know which of the first two comments I want to up vote more.

Comment: @djhurio: It's a string "NaN"

Comment: Here's a hint: `NaN != "NaN"`. Fix that.

Comment: @Jack Maney: I wish I know enough R programming to understand what you're talking about.:-(

Comment: First, worry about debugging your code to get rid of the string `"NaN"`. The error message (that you've just edited into your question) essentially told you as much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x` is a character vector because it contains a character `"NaN"`. Converting `x` to numeric will help.

```
x = c(2,3,4,NA,"NaN",3, 5)
class(x) # To see the class of x
round(as.numeric(x),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There should not be quotes around NaN. "NaN" is a character string; NaN is numeric. If this happens outside your toy example it suggests there is a problem elsewhere in your code.

```
x = c(2,3,4,NA,NaN,3, 5)
round(x,2)  
# [1]   2   3   4  NA NaN   3   5
```

Comment: my real data has NaN as a character string

Comment: @Amateur - Then you need to fix that. Change `"NaN"` to `NaN`.

Comment: @Amateur try to find where the "NaN"s are introduced. You can do this by searching for "NaN" (with the quotes).

Comment: @Ricardo djhurio's solution will work but my view is it would be better to identify the cause rather than use ```as.numeric(x)``` every time you wanted to work with ```x``` (or some other kludge).

Comment: I wanted to accept 2 answers but I couldn't so I upvoted both answers because they are both helpful. I ended up using as.numeric(x) for now but I am also looking for the cause of NaN.

Comment: @Amateur I am glad we were able to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
  library(plyr)

 round_any(x,1)
  [1]   2   3   4  NA NaN   3   5
```